# Python error: string index out of range

Tags: python, string

I try to update a game of n in a row. But when I try to update the array matrix i get the "string out of range error.

I made a while statement with `ind < len(board_height)`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix.py", line 61, in <module>
    drop_disk(print_board(1))
  File "matrix.py", line 23, in print_board
    (matrix[0][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][6]) +" |")
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is what my terminal spits out at me.

```
import tkinter 


def print_board(y):
    """Prints the board"""
    matrix = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

    matrix = str(y)

    print("\n")
    print("| " + str(matrix[0][0]) + " " + str(matrix[0][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][3]) +  " " + str 
    (matrix[0][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[0][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[1][0]) + " " + str(matrix[1][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[1][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[1][3]) +  " " + str 
    (matrix[1][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[1][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[1][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[2][0]) + " " + str(matrix[2][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[2][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[2][3]) +  " " + str 
    (matrix[2][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[2][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[2][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[3][0]) + " " + str(matrix[3][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[3][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[3][3]) +  " " + str         (matrix[3][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[3][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[3][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[4][0]) + " " + str(matrix[4][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[4][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[4][3]) +  " " + str      (matrix[4][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[4][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[4][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[5][0]) + " " + str(matrix[5][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[5][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[5][3]) +  " " + str         (matrix[5][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[5][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[5][6]) +" |")
    print("| " + str(matrix[6][0]) + " " + str(matrix[6][1]) +  " " + str(matrix[6][2]) +  " " + str(matrix[6][3]) +  " " + str      (matrix[6][4]) +  " " + str(matrix[6][5]) +  " " + str(matrix[6][6]) +" |")
    print("="*17)
    return matrix

def drop_disk(matrix):
    "Drops the disk in one of the seven columns"
    board_height = 7
    empty = 0   
    row = 0
    col = 0
    ind = 0

    player1 = input("Wat is de naam van speler 1?\n")
    player2 = input("Wat is de naam van speler 2?\n")


    column = int(input(player1 + ", In welke colom wil je je stuk laten vallen (1-7)?\n"))
    while ind < len(board_height):  
        for y in range(board_height):
            if matrix[row][col] == empty:
                y = matrix[row -1][col -1] = 1
                ind += 1
            return y
        return -1

drop_disk(print_board(1))
print_board(1)
```

Comment: I have heard of for loops but am unsure how to implement it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

error is because you are reassigning `matrix` to `str(y)`
so `matrix` changes to `str(y)` which is actually `'1'`.

`drop_disk(print_board(1))` # calls `print_board(1)` and sets `y = '1'`

```
def print_board(y): # assign y='1'
matrix = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] 

matrix = str(y) # matrix = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon on my question.  So Ho w do I update the matrix so I can print the new situation?   I'm still very new at Pyhon and programming.  All help is welcome.

Comment: So instead of changing an index in the array I just change the whole array to 1?

Comment: @KatyWatterniauxPeeters why you are assigning ``matrix`` to ``y``?

Comment: I try to update one cell in the matrix when a "coin" is droped in a row.  I was thinking that by assinging matrix to y i could feed it in the print_board function and print the updated matrix that way.

Comment: @KatyWatterniauxPeeters try another way, by this way you totally lost your matrix.and please mark correct if you find any help.